# Multiple line replace and carry in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have several text files with something simmilar to the following examples:

```
{
    {
        1,
        text1,
        text2,
    }
}
{
    {
        52,
        text1,
        text2,
    }
}
{
    {
        105,
        text1,
        text2,
    }
}
```

i was wonder how i could mass search through several files and replace them as follows:

```
{
    {
        17001,
        text1,
        text2,
    }
}
{
    {
        17052,
        text1,
        text2,
    }
}
{
    {
        17105,
        text1,
        text2,
    }
}
```

basically i would be adding 17,000 to each of the first numbers after each double opening brackets. I tried using \d\d\d to replace numbers with 17\d\d\d but then it would give me 17ddd the letter not the number. Help please

Comment: This sounds like a job for a programming language that can handle regular expressions, e.g., Python. Depending on what you know about programming that might be easier.

Comment: Welcome to Super User Stack Exchange. Stack Exchange communities are different than other sites. Please take the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) to see how this site works. Also review the Help Center sections on [topics to ask here](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [questions to avoid](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask), and [how to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). Please edit the question to show what you have in the find and replace boxes. That way we can try to help you.

Comment: Notepad++ cannot do arithmetic in regexp search/replace. You might be able to something using the [Python plugin](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/), but programming questions are off-topic here.

Comment: @DavidPostill Only if you have a small imagination. Just specify a replacement for every possible arithmetic result (i.e. replace 1 with 18, 2 with 19, 3 with 20 etc.). Duh ;)

Answer (score 4):

You have two problems:

1. In the replacement string `\d` means "print a `d`" and nothing more. All the regular expression special things like `\d` and `\w`, etc. only work in the search pattern, not the replacement string.
2. As @DavidPostill said, Notepad++ cannot do math in regexp search/replace.

You have three options to do what you want:

1. Use some program, script, or plugin to do the replacements for you. Any version of that is, as the previously mentioned comment says, off-topic here.
2. Use Notepad++ search and replace 3 times.

   - Round one for a single digit,
   - Round two for two digits, and
   - Round three for three digits.
3. If you have Notepad++ greater than v6.0 you can use PCRE syntax in the regexp, and use the [excellent answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1188040/multiple-line-replace-and-carry-in-notepad#1188682) by @ACR to do it all in one pass.

To accomplish this in the three-pass method, use the following steps. You may have to modify the search patterns to trap what you want, and only what you want. They work in the sample you provided above, but your files may be more complex than the sample.

### Round one

Find this:

```
(\s+)(\d),
```

Replace with this:

```
\11700\2,
```

### Round two

Find this:

```
(\s+)(\d\d),
```

Replace with this:

```
\1170\2,
```

### Round Three

Find this:

```
(\s+)(\d\d\d),
```

Replace with this:

```
\117\2,
```

### What it does

In the `Find this` pattern `\s+` finds all the whitespace that can be found before the next token, requiring at least one to prevent mathching a number following anything other than whitespace. The `()` around it make it the first captured string returned by the match. The `\d` matches one digit, and the groups `\d\d` and `\d\d\d` make it match 2 or three digits, exactly, instead. Again, the `()` turn it into a capturing group, the second one this time. Finally the `,` matches the comma after the numbers, which keeps it on the same line in your sample file.

In the `Replace with this`, the `\1` is replaced by the first capturing group (the spaces). `1700`, `170`, and `17` print the part that needs to be added to the line. The `\2` is replaced by the second capturing group, which is the digit(s) that you have in the find pattern. Finally the comma `,` is explicitly replaced, rather than wasting a capturing group for it.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this with a single find-and-replace. Notepad++ allows you to do a conditional replacement based on whether a group matched.

Find what:

```
^(\s*)(\d{3})?(\d{2})?(\d{1})?(,\s*)$
```

Replace with:

```
$1(?{2}17$2)(?{3}170$3)(?{4}1700$4)$5
```

## Explanation of Find-Expression

Proceeding from the outsides inward:

- The `^` and `$` characters mark the beginning and end of a line respectively.
- The `(\s*)` matches the whitespace at the beginning and the `(,\s*)` matches the comma and any trailing whitespace at the end of the line.
- In the middle we have three different groups to match either 3, 2 or 1 digits (using the `{n}` syntax). Each group is followed by a `?` to mark it as possibly not matching. The order of the groups is important, as the groups are matched in the order they appear. If there are three digits, the first group will match, and there will be no digits left for the following two groups two match. If the there are two digits, the first group will fail to match, the second group will match, and the first group will not have any digits to match.

## Explanation of Replace-Expression

- The `$1` and `$5` will match the whitespace at the beginning of the line and the comma and whitespace at the end of the line.
- The following groups (listed in the opposite order append "17" plus the correct number of zeroes based on which group was matched in the find-expression. For example, take the first group `(?{2}17$2)`. The `?{2}` checks to see whether group 2 was matched or not. If so, it inserts the following text: "17" plus the match for group 2, which should be a three-digit number.

Comment: Nice. I didn't think you could do it with a regexp +1